# add iteration number of for loop to legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add the number of the iteration a data point was added to the plot

At the moment I have:

```
for i in range(len(X_sample)):
    plt.plot(X_sample[i], Y_sample[i], 'kx', mew=3, color="green", label='samples')
```

I don't know how to get `i` into `label = ''`

Even better would be if the legend consists only of `label = 'samples'` but the iteration number is added right next to the data point within the plot.

Comment: Do you want `f'samples{i}'` or `'samples' + str(i)`?

Comment: *Even better would be*... look into [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).